# Calling a stored function that returns nothing

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, postgresql-10

I have this function which only inserts some data and returns nothing

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(srcDc integer, targetDc integer)

RETURNS void AS

$BODY$

BEGIN

INSERT INTO configurable_code(key_column,customer_discovery_scope_id)
SELECT key_column, targetDc FROM configurable_code WHERE customer_discovery_scope_id=srcDc
AND KEY_Column NOT IN (SELECT KEY_Column FROM configurable_code where customer_discovery_scope_id in( targetDc));

INSERT INTO user_customer_scope ( user_id, customer_discovery_scope_id )
SELECT user_id,targetDc FROM user_customer_scope where customer_discovery_scope_id=srcDc
AND customer_discovery_scope_id NOT IN (SELECT customer_discovery_scope_id FROM user_customer_scope where customer_discovery_scope_id = targetDc );

INSERT INTO user_scope_license ( user_id, customer_scope_id, license )
SELECT user_id,targetDc, license FROM user_scope_license WHERE customer_scope_id=srcDc
AND customer_scope_id NOT IN (SELECT customer_scope_id FROM user_scope_license where customer_scope_id = targetDc );

END;

$BODY$

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

COST 100;
```

And since the Postgres version is 10, procedures are not supported. So I use JDBCTemplate to make a simple call

```
jdbcTemplate.update("select test(?,?)",srcDc,targetDc);
```

But I get this error when running it

```
2022-02-02 17:03:22,640 [http-nio-8090-exec-4] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 0100E
2022-02-02 17:03:22,641 [http-nio-8090-exec-4] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - A result was returned when none was expected.
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: A result was returned when none was expected.
```

It seems to work with procedures but I can't use it because the version is 10. SimpleJDBCCall didn't work either. I can't use queryForObject as it requires a RowMapper. What would be the better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this in [the documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/callproc.html):

> The `escapeSyntaxCallMode` connection property controls how the driver transforms the call syntax to invoke functions or procedures.
>
> The default mode, `select`, supports backwards compatibility for existing applications and supports function invocation only. This is required to invoke a void returning function.

So you would call it like a stored procedure. Here is a complete code sample using JDBC:

```java
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

java.sql.Connection conn =
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/test?user=laurenz&escapeSyntaxCallMode=select"
    );

java.sql.CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{ call mumble(?) }");
stmt.setInt(1, 42);
stmt.execute();
stmt.close();

conn.close();
```

Comment: If I use "call test(?,?)" in update statement, it doesn't work. If I use SimpleJdbcCall, I get the following error:

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Cannot cast to boolean: "2"

Comment: This seems to work. But there is another issue. I don't want to hardcode the parameters. There is a jdbc.properties file in another project which is used to build WAR files and deploy. I know it can be done using Properties and FileStream but this is not a personal project that I have to do in my local system.

Comment: There is no need to hardcode any parameters.